# Azure Log Analytics - Join Fails - Inconsistent datatypes

Tags: azure, join, logging, types, analytics

I'm very new to Azure and the query language.
I've created a few alerts and queries which seem to work but I'm trying to make an hourly sweep looking for specific http errors and display them with a description as well as the code.

I used a join to a datatable but when I run the query it fails on the join.

```
Inconsistent data types for the join keys (responseCode_d, responseCode_d) (R64, I32)
```

responseCode_d is a numeric according to the Azure Analytics Query Schema and I declare it as an integer in my datatable. 
[responseCode_d schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y7UL.jpg)

Below is the query.

```
let codes = datatable(responseCode_d:int, description:string)
        [        400, "Endpoint - Not found",
                 500, "Internal server error",
                 415, "Unsupported Media"      
        ];
AzureDiagnostics
| join kind = inner
    codes on responseCode_d
| where responseCode_d == 500 or responseCode_d == 415 or responseCode_d == 400
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(1h)
| summarize count(responseCode_d) by description
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives a hint. (R64, I32)
There is a mismatch between the table column type (R64) and the type you specified for your table responseCode_d:int (I32).

Change datatable(**responseCode_d:int**, description:string)
to
datatable(**responseCode_d:double**, description:string)